# Where did the Petrine title of "First Among Equals" originate?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, papacy, peter

Contrary to the Roman Catholic assertion that Peter and his successors are the *Supreme Pontiff*, the Orthodox Catholic Churches assert that Peter and his successors hold the honorary title of the *First Among Equals*.

When was the actual title of *First Among Equals* used to define the Petrine bishopric?

I'm curious as to whether the Orthodox Churches began asserting this title specifically after the Schism began to take shape, or if it was something that the Latin Church decided to reject that was there from the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that your question is not about the *exact usage or origin* of the phrase *First Among Equals* rather the primacy of the bishop of Rome. i.e., The office of the bishop of Rome is considered preeminent.

The Orthodox Churches **did not begin** to assert this title after the Schism **nor did the Catholic Church reject it** after it. Both the churches always agreed that the bishop of Rome is first among the Pentarchy (Rome, Constantinople, Alexandria, Antioch and Jerusalem). The problem was on whether this primacy is just a honorary title or does it have functions/privileges attached to it (which is in and of itself a completely different question).

There has been many instances before the Schism which shows that the papal supremacy was an accepted fact.

- "For it is with this Roman church, by reason of its **more powerful preeminence that every other church**, that is to say all the faithful everywhere, ought to agree, inasmuch as in this church the apostolic tradition has been preserved continuously by those who come from everywhere."  St. Irenaeus ("Against All Heresies," c. 180 A.D.)
- The first bishop to claim primacy in writing was Pope Stephen I (254-257)
- Where Peter is, There is the Church - St. Ambrose, Archbishop of Milan ("Commentary on Twelve Psalms of David" c. 389 A.D.)
- "'But,' you [Jovinian] will say, 'it was on Peter that the Church was founded' [Matt. 16:18]. Well . . . **one among the twelve is chosen to be their head** in order to remove any occasion for division."  St. Jerome ("Against Jovinian," c. 393 A.D.)
- "Among these [apostles] Peter alone almost everywhere deserved to **represent the whole Church**."   St. Augustine of Hippo ("Sermon 295," c. 411 A.D.)
- Edicts of the Emperor Theodosius II and of Valentinian III proclaimed the Roman bishop as "**Rector of the whole Church**". The Emperor Justinian, who was living in the *East in Constantinople*, in the 6th century published a similar decree.
- First Council of Constantinople decreed: "The Bishop of Constantinople, however, shall have the prerogative of honor **after the Bishop of Rome** because Constantinople is New Rome.

They might have used different words, but neither the Catholic church nor the orthodox church has ever refused the primacy of the Bishop of Rome till today. They always considered him to be First Among Equals. It is whether this primacy has extra function is what is been questioned after the east-west schism.

Comment: I am specifically asking for an approx. date as to when this phrase was first used. What the Orthodox churches define as *First Among Equals* is dramatically different than what the Roman Church defines as *Supreme Pontiff*. Im somewhat knowledgeable of how the Schism happened. I just can't dig up any sources about the initial usage of *First Among Equals*.

Comment: "Wherefore we teach and declare that, by divine ordinance, the Roman Church possesses a pre-eminence of ordinary power over every other Church, and that this jurisdictional power of the Roman Pontiff is both episcopal and immediate. Both clergy and faithful, of whatever rite and dignity, both singly and collectively, are bound to submit to this power by the duty of hierarchical subordination and true obedience, and this not only in matters concerning faith and morals, but also in those which regard the discipline and government of the Church throughout the world." Vatican I, Chapt.3

Comment: The above canon clearly leaves no room what so ever  for a conciliatory church structure...which is *exactly* what the title *First Among Equals* calls for.

Comment: "Furthermore, we declare, we proclaim, we define that it is absolutely necessary for salvation that every human creature be subject to the Roman Pontiff."  Pope Boniface VIII, Unam sanctam, 1302ad.

Comment: It is an undeniable, empirical, and dogmatic fact that the Roman Catholic Church requires Catholics to believe that *no one* ever has been, or ever will be, "equal" to the Bishop of Rome. Im wanting to know if there are any writings of the Church Fathers that specifically say the Bishop of Rome is "First but not supreme."

Comment: You said: **They might have used different words, but neither the Catholic church nor the orthodox church has ever refused the primacy of the Bishop of Rome till today. They always considered him to be First Among Equals.**  You are correct in stating that they both have considered the Bishop of Rome  to have honorary primacy, but it is only the Eastern churches that have used the phrase *first among equals*.

Comment: I don't think Catholics believe that _no one ever has been, or ever will be, "equal" to the Bishop of Rome_, rather they believe at any given instance only one can have the authority of the pope. I am personally not aware of any church fathers saying that the Bishop of Rome is _First but not supreme_. If any one did orthodox church would have gladly used it against papal supremacy. Since they could not find any I doubt I can.

Comment: There is a Quartodecimanism controversy in early church in which Pope Victor I tried to excommunicate a bunch of churches outside of Rome. Some big name bishops convinced him not to do it in a harsh tone. But none of them said to him that he did not have the authority to do so. Which implies that they accepted that he can do it, but that he should not do it because it will destroy the unity of the church.

Comment: Also you seem to be of the understanding that the term _first among equals_ and the term _supreme pontiff_ are not compatible with each other.In a catholic understanding they are compatible. As a bishop, the bishop of Rome is equal to any other bishop in the world. The CCC goes in length to explain this. The bishops should not be thought of as vicars of the Pope. All Bishops receive their authority from Christ not pope. The bishop of Rome has extra duties in order to protect the unity of the Church. Pope is NOT the ruler of the church rather a guardian of it.

Comment: The canons of Vatican I are very straight forward. 1. *..the Roman Church possesses a pre-eminence of ordinary power over every other Church..* (All other churches in the universe are not equal to the Roman Church) 2. *..this jurisdictional power of the Roman Pontiff is both episcopal and immediate.* (the Pope alone can universally and exclusively macro/micro manage)

Comment: 3. **Both clergy and faithful, of whatever rite and dignity, both singly and collectively, are bound to submit to this power by the duty of hierarchical subordination and true obedience..** (*all* clergy including *all* bishops *must* submit to the Roman Pontiff's jurisdictional power) 4. **..this not only in matters concerning faith and morals, but also in those which regard the discipline and government of the Church throughout the world** (the Pope ultimately has supreme and universal jurisdictional power over absolutely *all* things Catholic) I would love to continue this in chat format :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11027/discussion-between-jayarathina-madharasan-and-charles-alsobrook)

Comment: @user5286 Vatican I took place in the 1870s.  Is there a particular reason that you cite that particular reference, since the anathema between Rome and Constantinople, which was current then, is no more?